# Azure Mobile Client, how to do a bulk insert in Angular 4?

Tags: performance, angular, azure

I am current using the js library:

```
<script src="//zumo.blob.core.windows.net/sdk/azure-mobile-apps-client.2.0.0.js"></script>
```

And I am currently trying to do a bulk insert instead of foreach. Is there any method call, that I can use?

```
addSubjectSpecialization(specialization): Promise<any>{
        var orderTable = this.client.getTable("specialization");
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            orderTable.insert(specialization).then((res) => {
                resolve(res);
            }, (err) => reject(err))
        })
    }
```

In my component I am doing a foreach, to insert multiple objects. Is there any better way? That means: Instead of foreach, do we have a function for bulk insert?

Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-html-how-to-use-client-library#inserting
Note: I have seen the suggestions provided by Stackoverflow. And none solves the issue. The suggestions where MobileClient(.Net) has tableStorage bulk insert. And I am not sure how can I do it in typescript.

Comment: *"better"* how? *"I have seen the suggestions provided by Stackoverflow"* - which, specifically? *"And none solves the issue"* - what happens instead?

Comment: Thanks @jonrsharpe I have updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there is no function we can use for bulk insert. But you may post a feature request on [this Github repository](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-js-client/issues).